# MSMQ Access to Message Queuing system is denied when trying to receive message

Tags: msmq

I can't figure out why I'm getting a 'Access to Message Queuing system is denied' error when trying to receive a message from a remote queue. (Msmq 5.0).

Sending to the queue is no problem, receiving from it is.

The security of the queue itself is configured to give full control to everyone and anonymous.

Any idea why sending to this queue doesn't work? (firewall is not the issue because the error is the same with all firewalls turned off.).

Comment: When you say "receiving" how are you receiving the message, do you have a console app picking up the messages off the queue or a trigger picking up the messages?

Comment: Hi, I found the answer yesterday. DTC wasn't enabled for remote clients. A different error would have been clearer to me than just Access Denied.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer yesterday. DTC wasn't enabled for remote clients. A different error would have been clearer to me than just Access Denied.

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699854(v=vs.85).aspx).Although remote read operations are not part of the optimal messaging model, reading messages from remote nontransactional queues is fully supported. Remote reading is typically used to distribute the work load among servers. Remote reading is a high-overhead and therefore inefficient process. Including remote read operations in an application limits scaling.

So Consider this:

> Applications running on computers running a member of the family with
>   MSMQ 3.0 installed in workgroup mode will use the secured remote read
>   API. Workgroup computers cannot establish an encrypted channel for
>   remote reading, and, by default, the Message Queuing server hosting
>   the queue containing the message to be read accepts requests from
>   workgroup computers on a non-encrypted channel. To modify this default
>   behavior so that the MSMQ 3.0 server rejects requests from workgroup
>   computers, add the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\NewRemoteReadServerDenyWorkgroupClient
>   registry entry (a DWORD) and set it to 1.

Comment: This link helped to resolve my issue with remote receive operation though not the registry setting quoted in the answer but this one set to 1: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient`.